# GIT LFS commit a huge update

Tags: github, branching-and-merging, git-lfs

I have “folder A” with a project (App).
I spent quite such time working on lots of updates and when I finish - I created a build.
Now the “folder A” is 2GB+.
When I try to push it to the master, obviously GitHub shows an Error, saying that the file is 100mb plus.

Question: how can I push the big update with lots of changes files  (45K) and new size 2GB+.

P.S. I am aware about GitLFS, but I only know how to commit big files one by one tracking them individually, but not the whole folder.

P.S.S. At the moment I have “folder A” which is the latest version with all of the updates and “folder B”, which is the version, before the last failed commit. So if there is a way to push “folder A” so it’s merged with “folder B” - it would be brilliant, but I have no idea, how to do it.

Thanks in advance!

P.S.S.S. Yes, I should have used branches - my bad…

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix by myself. Maybe it would save the day to someone:

1. Create a branch
2. Make adjustments to the branch. (Copy-replace everything from "folder B" with data from "folder A".
3. Commit the branch (without pushing, as you won't be able due to the big size)
   [terminal part]
4. target the branch
   `cd /Users/mainuser/Desktop/YourFolder`
5. get information about the big files
   `git lfs migrate info`
6. convert big files to lfs
   `git lfs migrate import`
7. push
   `git push`
8. pull to the main branch